# Can I set this axis style in python plotly

Tags: plotly-python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZthRp.png)

I am plotting a ganttChart in python-plotly,can I set this axis style in plotly ganttChart?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time of this answer, the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/) does not have enough features to create what you are looking for. The best you can do is change the background color and text color which is extremely far from what you need.

[image]

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'


df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01',
         Finish='2009-02-28', Completion_pct=50),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05',
         Finish='2009-04-15', Completion_pct=25),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20',
         Finish='2009-05-30', Completion_pct=75)
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish",
                  y="Task",
                  )
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_xaxes(color="#ffffff")
fig.update_yaxes(color="#ffffff")
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor="#48596f")
fig.show()
```